# How to override phtml using custom module

Tags: overrides

I want to override two phtml one is product view.phtml and another one is addtocart.phtml

I m trying this code:

```
<catalog_product_view>

    <reference name="product.info">
          <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>coupon/catalog/product/view.phtml</template>
        </action>  

    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

now i m copy catalog/product/ view.phtml  and paste in my file and change what i want to change

Using this i can override view phtml but i m not getting proper phtml

i m attaching image

[image]

is this correct way to override view phtml

Comment: can you please tell where you have pasted this xml code?

Comment: in my module xml

Comment: Your code same to right.May be some code missing  on your `coupon/catalog/product/view.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

For ovveriding, you don't need xml.

Make sure you have a theme set to the package. 
In you case, a folder with this path: 
`app/design/frontpage/rwd/mytheme/template`

Within the template folder, you can now get any file from /base/default or rwd/default and override it in you theme folder.

Have a look into the magento designers guide. There's the template hirarchie better explained then I do this here.

If you use extension like AOE Template Hints, you'll be able to identify blocks much faster.

Answer (score 0):

replace `<template>` with `<name>` tag

```
<reference name="product.info">
      <action method="setTemplate"><name>coupon/catalog/product/view.phtml</name></action>  

</reference>
```